# Perforce branching vs git branching

Tags: git, perforce

I am a Git user trying to learn Perforce.

In Git a user can checkout from the main branch, change some files and push his code to the server on a different branch with a specific commit ID.

Another Git user can checkout that new branch using its commit ID and work on top of it.

How can this be performed using Perforce?

Comment: Are you using streams or just traditional perforce branches?   A lot of this depends on what your mode of operation and structure are.  There are lightweight branches in streams and there is also using shelving to create temporary working pseudo-changes.  So much is dependent upon your organization's structure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I am a Git user trying to learn Perforce.

I'm sorry.

> How can this be performed using Perforce?

I'm a better Git user than I am a Perforce user, so correct me if anything appears wrong. I highly recommend reading the man pages and [a tutorial](http://www.vaccaperna.co.uk/scm/branching.html).

It "can't" be, at least not quite the way Git does it.

In `git`, when you create a branch, you're branching *the entire state of the repository*. Perforce does not support this, rather, it's "branching" is more *per-file*: i.e., you branch file A into file B, at which point file B contains a back reference to file A saying "I came from here." This back reference can then be used to determine a common ancestor for merging purposes. My understanding, however, is that these back references are per-file, and you are free to integrate (merge) any file into any other. (Compare to git, where "Parent commit" is your back-reference, but is on a whole-repository scale.)

You can branch entire sets of files using [`p4 integrate`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrate.html), using the typical Perforce syntax (e.g., `//depot/some/path/...`). Typically, you'd branch a whole directory to a whole other directory, such as `//depot/main/my_project` into `//depot/release-1.0/my_project`, or something similar. Perforce, as far as I know, doesn't really care about the paths: it just "branches" files from one location to another. Any pattern or sanity in the paths is up to you.

Additionally, you can use [`p4 branch`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_branch.html) to create "branch specifications", which are basically a way to record the source set of files and their destinations, to make branching easier. (If you take the release example, you may want to eventually merge back changes, or merge further changes into the release, etc.)

Both times I've worked with Perforce, branches were a beast of a different nature than in Git, and there's a bit of a culture difference here. Branches were comparatively rare. (I only saw them used for releases, ever.) We did not use them for feature branches, except perhaps the largest of features; compare to `git`, where to me a "feature branch" is usually "it took >1 commit".

Comment: As gaige said in a comment to the original question it depends on your organization. Perforce is centrally organized, so it is up to a central instance to decide if features branches, QA branches, release branches etc. are wanted or not. It is general practice to not let users of a bigger organization decide over branches (how many and where). However you might think about using the git-p4 bridge.

Comment: @pitseeker: "It is general practice to not let users [have control] over branches (how many and where)" This is perhaps a bit more extreme than what I've seen (but doesn't sound implausible, sadly)… (the org usually had a pattern to follow, given that things can otherwise get disorganized quickly). The way you describe it is unfortunate, and would seem to prevent a critical part of an engineer's job.

Comment: *I'm sorry.* Made me laugh far more than I should have.

Comment: Downvote for lack of mention of Streams. In particular, "Lightweight Branching using Task Streams" is what you want to look at.

Comment: The tutorial link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If you despise Perforce as much as I do then you should continue using Git.
I should say that I'm much more comfortable using Git.

I currently use Git-P4 + a set of Bash scripts I wrote ([git-p4-helpers](https://github.com/pgpbpadilla/git-p4-helpers))

I follow a simplified variation of [this workflow](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/01/work-with-git-and-perforce/):

```bash
$ git checkout p4-integration
$ git p4 sync
$ git p4 rebase
$ git tag last-green <SHA1> # last green build
$ git rebase last-green develop
$ git checkout -b <my-feature>
$ git commit # as needed
# Sync Git->P4 (see Github:git-p4-helpers)
# Submit using P4
```

There's still one thing I haven't been able to figure out, namely how to submit from Git-P4 to P4 fast (every time I have tried it takes forever to doing `git p4 sync` then a bunch of other stuff that make it very annoying to submit from my Git repo directly to P4. So I wrote a script to sync my Git repo with my P4 workspace and then Submit using P4.

For now this allows me to use all the features of Git while I'm working on my changes, then I just submit using P4.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that perforce makes a copy for a branch where Git just makes a pointer to the new branch, which is much faster.